# Is "implements Comparable<Foo>" redundant for enums?

Tags: java, enums, comparable

In the following example, is there any difference in behavior or allowed usages for the enum `Foo` with or without the `implements Comparable<Foo>`?

```
enum Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {
    a, b, c
}
```

I'm not interested in differences observable through reflection (e.g. by calling `Foo.class.getInterfaces()`), but if there are any more such differences you know of, please note them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it clearly is:

```
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
        implements Comparable<E>, Serializable { ... }
```

Any enum `MyEnum` is automatically `Comparable<MyEnum>`.